# How to useFormik pass Props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

using Reactjs with typescript

I want to pass the useFormik hook to the component props.

The reason for this is to reduce unnecessary lines and increase reuse.

My current code

```
...
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { userName: ''},
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {}
})

return (
  <Form>
    {/* A place to make a component. */}
    <Text
       id="userName"
       fullWidth
       label="Name"
       defaultValue={formik.values.userName}
       onChange={formik.handleChange}
       onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
       error={formik.touched.userName && Boolean(formik.errors.userName)}
       helperText={formik.touched.userName && formik.errors.userName}
    >
    {/* A place to make a component. */}
  </Form>
)
```

Custom component, which is the main point of the question.

```
interface props {
    id: string;
    formik : what, // How do I deliver the prop here?
  }

const TextFieldCustom = ({ id, formik }: props) => {
    return (
     <Text
         id={id}
         fullWidth
         label={id}
         defaultValue={formik.values.userName}
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
         error={formik.touched.userName && Boolean(formik.errors.userName)}
         helperText={formik.touched.userName && formik.errors.userName}
    >

  );
};
```

My code completed because of your answer.

```
...
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { userName: ''},
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {}
})

return (
  <Form>
    {/* A place to make a component. */}
    <TextFieldCustom id="username" formik={formik}/>
    {/* A place to make a component. */}
  </Form>
)
```

I want your good solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access formik helpers from the child component you can use useFormikContext. I think it's easier.

From your code I would also recommend to use Formik component as parent of Form component as it needs it but that could be another thing.

Here's what I would do (note that I've substituted Form component in favor of form html tag):

Parent component:

```
export interface IFormData {
  username: string;
}

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  userName: Yup.string()
    .required("Username required"),
});

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const formikConfig = useFormik({
    initialValues: { userName: "" },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {},
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formikConfig.handleSubmit}>
      <TextCompo id="id" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

Children component:

```
interface ITextCompoProps {
  id: string;
}

const TextFieldCustom = (props: ITextCompoProps) => {
  const { id } = props;
  const context = useFormikContext<IFormData>();

  return (
    <Text
      id={id}
      fullWidth
      label={id}
      defaultValue={context.values.userName}
      onChange={context.handleChange}
      onBlur={context.handleBlur}
      error={!!(context.errors.username && context.touched.username)}
      helperText={context.touched.username && context.errors.username}
    />
  );
};

export default TextFieldCustom;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormikProps

```
import { FormikProps } from 'formik';

interface props {
    id: string;
    formik : FormikProps<{username: string}>
  }

const TextFieldCustom = ({ id, formik }: props) => {
    return (
     <Text
         id={id}
         fullWidth
         label={id}
         defaultValue={formik.values.userName}
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
         error={formik.touched.userName && Boolean(formik.errors.userName)}
         helperText={formik.touched.userName && formik.errors.userName}
    >

  );
};
```