# useFormikContext Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, react-context

I want to pass formik as a prop to Child Component **CustomFormGroup** and my Parent component is the **Profile** I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358702/how-to-useformik-pass-props) answer. In Proflie component I'm getting Error. *Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.*

**Component**

```
import Input from "antd/lib/input/Input";
import { customFormGroupProps } from "../types";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";

const CustomFormGroup = (props: customFormGroupProps) => {
  const context = useFormikContext<customFormGroupProps>();
  console.log(context);
  return (
    <div>
      <label className='mt-1'>{props.labelName}</label>
      <Input
        placeholder={props.placeholder} 
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomFormGroup;
```

**type is as follows**

```
export interface customFormGroupProps {
  labelName: string;
  placeholder: string;
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import CustomFormGroup from "../utils/CustomFormGroup";
import formik from "./profileConfig";
import Form from "antd/lib/form/Form";

const Profile = () => {
  return (
          <Form onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <CustomFormGroup labelName="Name" placeholder="Jhon Doe" />
          </Form>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

**profileConfig file**

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues:{
    name:""
  },
  onSubmit: values => {
    console.log(values.name);
  }
});
export default formik;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use hooks outside a component function, it is simply how they work. But, you can make a composition of hooks.

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues:{
    name:""
  },
  onSubmit: values => {
    console.log(values.name);
  }
});
```

Just do it like this

```
import CustomFormGroup from "../utils/CustomFormGroup";
import Form from "antd/lib/form/Form";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

const Profile = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
     initialValues:{
     name:""
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
    console.log(values.name);
   }
  });
  return (
          <Form onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <CustomFormGroup labelName="Name" placeholder="Jhon Doe" />
          </Form>
  );
};

export default Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `useFormik()` in `profileConfig` file because it is not inside  a React component. `useFormik()` is a custom React hook from Formik and hooks don't work outside React components.

To fix, move it to `Profile` component.

```js
const Profile = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues:{
      name:""
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      console.log(values.name);
    }
  });
  return (
    <Form onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <CustomFormGroup labelName="Name" placeholder="Jhon Doe" />
    </Form>
  );
};
```